# Does there exist continuous map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ for uncountably many $x,y$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity

Does there exist continuous map from $S^1$ to $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ for uncountably many $x,y\in S^1$?
By the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem), I know there is no injective map from $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^1$.

If we consider some map like $g(x)=f(x)-f(-x)$ for $x\in S^1$, I can say by the intermediate value theorem that there is at least one point where $g$ vanishes; is that vanishing set uncountable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any constant map $f:\mathbb{S}^1\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and would satisfy $f(x)=f(y)$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb{S}^1$, of which there are certainly uncountably many.

In fact, a continuous map $f$ that is only constant on a non-empty open set of $\mathbb{S}^1$ would have $f(x)=f(y)$ for uncountably many $x,y\in\mathbb{S}^1$, because any non-empty open set of $\mathbb{S}^1$ is uncountable.

Comment: Actually there are no other cases where this can happen, as any such uncountable set would have to be dense somewhere but is also closed.

Comment: @canaaerus I do not understand your comment would you please explain it?

Comment: The stronger claim, that every continuous map $f:S^1 \to \mathbb{R}$ has these uncountably many pairs, [has been posed and answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566884/f-bf-s1-to-bf-r-there-exist-uncountably-many-pairs-of-distinct-points-x).