# what is the cardinality of the set ??

Tags: general-topology

Let $f:S^1\to\mathbb{R}$ be any continuous function where $S^1=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:x^2+y^2=1\}$ . What is the cardinality of this set $T=\{(a,b),a\in S^1,b\in S^1$ and $a\neq b:f(a)=f(b)\}$??

---

$S^1$ is connected and compact and continuous image of connected and compact is also connected and compact .I think it would be use here but don't know ...

Comment: or see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1566884/f-bf-s1-to-bf-r-there-exist-uncountably-many-pairs-of-distinct-points-x)

Comment: ohh thank you .. should i delete this post ??

Comment: Note that while the _title_ of the previous question just asks for a proof that $T$ is _uncountable_, some of the answers do get extremely close to asserting what its actual cardinality is.